# Не понимаю как создать логику вычитания/сложения

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть выпадающее меню `month__wrapper` с месяцами (появляется при наведении на месяц), при клике на который срабатывает слушатель и заполняет календарь. 
Вот код, где всё это происходит и пояснение:
`i` - месяц на который кликнули, 0 - январь, 1 - февраль, и т.д.
`calendarNumber` - разница в месяцах от текущего месяца
`month` - текущий месяц, который в календаре
`logicCalendar()` - отрисовывает календарь, берёт текущий месяц, добавляет значение `calendarNumber` и отрисовывает календарь

```js
if (text === months[i]) {
    let month = calendarNumber + startDate.getMonth();
    month = month%12;
    if (i < month) {
        calendarNumber = i - month;
    } else if (i > month) {
        calendarNumber = i + calendarNumber;
    }
    clearDays();
    logicCalendar();
}
```

Как должна работать программа:
Я кликаю по октябрю, `calendarNumber` равняется -1
Кликаю по сентябрю, `calendarNumber` равняется -2
Кликаю по августу, `calendarNumber` равняется -3
Кликаю по июлю, `calendarNumber` равняется -4
Кликаю по декабрю, `calendarNumber` равняется 1
`calendarNumber` - это разница от текущего месяца (ноября)

Фунция `logicCalendar()`, которая отрисовывает календарь работает без ошибок, это можно посмотреть, если покликать месяца влево и вправо
Программа должна переходить на месяца, только в этом году(если прокликать до 2023 года и кликнуть на январь, тебя кинет на январь 2019 года)
Если покликать на разные месяца, то выводятся не те месяца, на которые кликал

Как должен выглядеть код:

```js
if (text === months[i]) {
    // тут проверка
    // calendarNumber равняется разнице от текущего месяца
    clearDays();
    logicCalendar();
}
```

```js
Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
 return 33 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 33).getDate();
};
let calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar');
let weeks = [...calendar.querySelectorAll('.week')];
let calendar__month = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__month');
let calendar__year = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__year');
let calendar__left = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__left');
let calendar__right = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__right');
let months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
let calendarNumber = 0;
let month__wrapper = calendar.querySelector('.month__wrapper');

let days = [];
for (let i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
 for (let j = 0; j < weeks[i].children.length; j++) {
  days.push(weeks[i].children[j]);
 }
}
let thisMonth = function (month) {
 return months[month];
};

let elem = document.createElement('span');
let startDate = new Date();

month__wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 let text = event.target.lastChild.data;
 for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  if (text === months[i]) {
   let month = calendarNumber + startDate.getMonth();
   month = month%12;
   console.log(month + ' month');
   if (i < month) {
    calendarNumber = i - month;
   } else if (i > month) {
    calendarNumber = i + calendarNumber;
   }
   console.log(i + ' i');
   console.log(calendarNumber + ' calendarNumber');
   clearDays();
   logicCalendar();
   month = calendarNumber + startDate.getMonth();
   console.log(month + ' month');
   console.log(' ');
  }
 }
});

calendar__left.addEventListener('click', () => {
 calendarNumber--;
 clearDays();
 logicCalendar();
});

calendar__right.addEventListener('click', () => {
 calendarNumber++;
 clearDays();
 logicCalendar('true');
});

function logicCalendar(bool) {
 let thisDate = new Date();
 if (startDate.getMonth() !== thisDate.getMonth()) {
  if (bool === 'true') {
   calendarNumber--;
  }
 }
 let thisDay = thisDate.getDate();
 thisDate.setDate(1);
 let sum = thisDate.getMonth() + calendarNumber;
 let year = parseInt(sum / 12, 10);
 sum %= 12;
  if (sum < 0) {
  sum = 12 + sum;
 }
 thisDate.setMonth(sum);
 let thisYear = thisDate.getFullYear() + year;
 let dayWeek = thisDate.getDay();
 if (dayWeek == 0) {
  dayWeek = 6;
 } else {
  dayWeek--;
 }
 thisDate.setDate(thisDay);
 let daysClone = days.slice();
 daysClone.splice(0, dayWeek);
 let day = 1;
 for (let i = 0; i < thisDate.daysInMonth(); i++) {
  daysClone[i].innerHTML = day;
  day++;
 }
 if (calendarNumber === 0) {
  daysClone[thisDay-1].classList.add('today');
 }
 elem.innerHTML = thisMonth(sum);
 calendar__month.prepend(elem);
 calendar__year.innerHTML = thisYear;
}

function clearDays() {
 for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].innerHTML = '';
  if (days[i].classList.contains('today')) {
   days[i].classList.remove('today');
  }
 }
}

logicCalendar();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

:root {
  --gray: #333333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.calendar {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.calendar__date {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.calendar__month {
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: block;
}

.month__wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 600;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out,
    visibility .2s ease-in-out;
}

.month__wrapper .month {
 padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

.month__wrapper .month:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.month__wrapper .month:hover {
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}

.calendar__month:hover .month__wrapper {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar__top {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}

.calendar__right, .calendar__left {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.day__week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 6px 0;
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
}

.day__month {
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
}

.week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.week > div {
 background-color: #f3f2f2;
 flex: 1;
 height: 40px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 19px;
}

.week > div:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.week:not(:last-child) div {
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

div.today {
 background-color: #ee5728;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
 <div class="calendar__top">
  <div class="calendar__left">«</div>
  <div class="calendar__date">
   <span class="calendar__month">
    <div class="month__wrapper">
     <div class="month">Январь</div>
     <div class="month">Февраль</div>
     <div class="month">Март</div>
     <div class="month">Апрель</div>
     <div class="month">Май</div>
     <div class="month">Июнь</div>
     <div class="month">Июль</div>
     <div class="month">Август</div>
     <div class="month">Сентябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Октябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Ноябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Декабрь</div>
    </div>
   </span>
   <span class="calendar__year"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__right">»</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__week">
  <div>Пн</div>
  <div>Вт</div>
  <div>Ср</div>
  <div>Чт</div>
  <div>Пт</div>
  <div>Сб</div>
  <div>Вс</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__month">
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> <!-- .calendar -->
```

Comment: "то получаются ошибки" - ??

Comment: @Igor выводится не тот месяц

Comment: Не понятно, что происходит в `logicCalendar()`... Можно начать с её изменения так, чтобы она получала конкретный год и месяц в качесвте аргумента и рисовала числа исходя от них. Независимо от внешних переменных... В итоге, как отметили: Легче переписать, чем исправить)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, она зависима от `calendarNumber`, я дописал пояснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный код выглядит так:

```js
if (text === months[i]) {
    let year = (calendarNumber + startDate.getMonth())/12;
    year = Math.floor(year)*12;
    calendarNumber = i - startDate.getMonth() + year;
    clearDays();
    logicCalendar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы столкнулись с действием леммы, вытекающей из аксиомы: *"Читать код труднее, чем писать код."* Лемма формулируется так: *"Если Вы пишете код на пределе Ваших способностей, то Вам придется найти кого-то умнее Вас, чтобы поддерживать и отлаживать этот код."*

Comment: Я просто писал код 3 дня подряд, в этом проблема)