# Помогите разобраться в крестиках коликах на JS

Tags: javascript

Я написал игру крестики нолики на JS, теперь хочу поменять его, чтобы игрок играл против компа.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Мой код

```js
var gameBlock = document.getElementById('game'), 
    playerIndex = 1, players = ['O','X'], 
    resultValues = [],
    winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]];
      
    function isWinning(value) {
      var combination, i, j;
        
      for (i = 0; i < winningCombinations.length; i++) {
        combination = winningCombinations[i];
          
        for (j = 0; j < combination.length; j++) {
          if (resultValues[combination[j]] != value) break;
        }
          
        if (j == 3) return true;
      }
        
      return false;
    }

    function reset() {
      var i, inputs = gameBlock.getElementsByTagName('input');
      
      for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = inputs[i].value = '';
      }
       
      playerIndex = 1;
      resultValues = [];
    }

    function resetIfWinnerFound() {
      var i, inputs = gameBlock.getElementsByTagName('input');
   
      for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        resultValues[i] = inputs[i].value;
      }
        
      for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (isWinning(players[i])) {
          alert('Победитель '+ players[i] + '!');
          reset();
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    function onClick(sender) {
      sender.disabled = "disabled";
      sender.value = players[playerIndex];

      playerIndex == 1 ? playerIndex-- : playerIndex++;
        
      resetIfWinnerFound();
    }
```

```css
body {
 background-image: url(https://wallpaperlayer.com/img/2015/4/awesome-yellow-wallpaper-76-120-hd-wallpapers.jpg);
 width: 100%;
}

.gameblock {
 padding-top: 100px;
 width: 480px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#block {
 margin-top: 4px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid #000000;
 font-size: 42px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-weight: 900;
 transition: 0.3s;
 color: #000000;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#game input {
 border: 3px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    font-size: 62px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 4px;
}

#block:hover {
 margin-top: 4px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid #000000;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #f9b533;
}

#block:active {
 margin-top: 4px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid #000000;
 background-color: #f8cf7f;
}

#block:disabled {
 font-size: 62px;
 transition: 0.3s;
 background-color: #fbdf7f;
}

#resetButton {
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: 700;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 40px;
 width: 465px;
 margin-left: 4px;
 transition: 0.3s;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#resetButton:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #f9b533;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: 700;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 40px;
 width: 465px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>X & O</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gameblock" id="game">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num0" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num1" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num2" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num3" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num4" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num5" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num6" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num7" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <input type="button" value="" name="num8" onclick="onClick(this)" id="block">
            <button type="button" id="resetButton" onclick="reset()">New Game</button>
        </div>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Помочь разобраться в собственном коде? 2. Комп должен просто играть или выигрывать?

Comment: Комп должен играть, желательно чтобы всегда выиграл.

Comment: При правильной игре с обеих сторон в крестики-нолики 3х3 невозможно выиграть.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052675/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1052681#1052681

Comment: @Igor 1. Игрок за компом не обязан использовать правильную стратегию. 2. Комп может использовать рандомную стратегию и проигрывать правильной стратегии пользователя.